# How to interpret two observations that are otherwise identical in a regression model

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am confused trying to interpret how two observations are otherwise identical but differ by a dummy variable. For example if we have the following model with a factor variable **race** being **White race** the reference category:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Score ~ ., data = pisaTrain)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-247.44  -48.86    1.86   49.77  217.18 

Coefficients:
                                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                   143.766333  33.841226   4.248 2.24e-05 ***
grade                                          29.542707   2.937399  10.057  < 2e-16 ***
male                                          -14.521653   3.155926  -4.601 4.42e-06 ***
raceEuropean                                  -67.277327  16.786935  -4.008 6.32e-05 ***
raceAsian                                     -4.110325   9.220071  -0.446  0.65578    
raceBlack                                     -67.012347   5.460883 -12.271  < 2e-16 ***
raceHispanic                                   38.975486   5.177743  -7.528 7.29e-14 ***
raceOther                                     -16.922522   8.496268  -1.992  0.04651 *
```

Given two people that are otherwise identical, what would be the absolute difference in predicted score given that one person is **European**  and the other is **Hispanic**? Also in the case when the race is **white**, the difference will differ by the coefficient on other variables?

Somebody might help me out, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your only difference is **European** vs **Hispanic** you can reason like this.  Everything besides the race factor is the same, so let's just call the contributions of all of those $S$ for same.  Then:

$$ E = S + -67.27 \times 1 $$
$$ H = S + 38.98 \times 1 $$

So the difference is:

$$ E - H = (S + -67.27) - (S + 38.98) = -67.27 - 39.98 $$

because the $S$'s cancel.  In the case of **white**, the calculation would be:

$$ W = S $$

so

$$ E - W = (S + -67.27) - S = -67.27 $$